# raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:]) ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'django~=1.9.0', 'at', '~=1.9.0')

Tags: python, django, windows, windows-7, pip

I am following [this tutorial](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/) on Windows 7 with Python 3. However I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\jalal> C:/Python34/python -m pip install django~=1.9.0
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 172, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'django~=1.9.0', 'at', '~=1.9.0')

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\jalal\pip\pip.log

PS C:\Users\jalal> pip -v
The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
g of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ pip <<<<  -v
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried it with -r flag as mentioned in an Stackoverflow response however I got this error.

```
PS C:\Users\jalal> C:/Python34/python -m pip install -r django~=1.9.0
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'django~=1.9.0'
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\jalal\pip\pip.log
```

What's the solution to this problem?

More info:

```
pip 1.5.6 from C:\Users\jalal\myvenv\lib\site-packages (python 3.4)
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\jalal> pip freeze
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\jalal>
```

`pip freeze` shows nothing.

This is what I get without `-r` flag:

```
PS C:\Users\jalal> C:/Python34/python -m pip install django~=1.9.0
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 172, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'django~=1.9.0', 'at', '~=1.9.0')

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\jalal\pip\pip.log
```

I also tried installing pip and then using the following command but still got error:

```
PS C:\Users\jalal> myvenv\Scripts\activate
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\jalal> pip install django~=1.9.0
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jalal\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\jalal\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "C:\Users\jalal\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 172, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "C:\Users\jalal\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "C:\Users\jalal\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "C:\Users\jalal\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requireme
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "C:\Users\jalal\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'django~=1.9.0', 'at', '~=1.9.0')

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\jalal\pip\pip.log
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\jalal>
```

Comment: What version of `pip` are you using? Maybe you need to update? `easy_install -U pip`

Comment: pip 1.5.6 from C:\Users\jalal\myvenv\lib\site-packages (python 3.4) @jape

Comment: Try doing `python -m pip install -U pip`, and then `pip install django~=1.9.0`

Comment: @jape I followed your instructions but got error. Please have a look at the end of the question for my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that version (1.5.6) of `pip` does not recognize the *compatible release* specifier `~=`.

You can try the following version specifications which are equivalent to `~=1.9.0`:

```
pip install django>=1.9.0
```

Or:

```
pip install django==1.9.*
```

In any case, you may also want to upgrade to the latest version of `pip` using:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: the first command worked but not the second one. Got this error for the second one `    "Expected ',' or end-of-list in",line,"at",line[p:]
ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'django==1.9.*', 'at', '*')` Thank you!

Comment: when I tried your upgrade command got this error `File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 372, in _rmtree_uns
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\jalal\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py"
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\jalal\pip\pip.log`

Comment: @MonaJalal That's quite strange. How did you setup your `virtualenv`?

Comment: using activate in powershell

Answer (score 0):

Do away with `-r` unless you are reading from a file. Use:

```
C:/Python34/python -m pip install django~=1.9.0
```